# Is a tensor always identifiable as some symbol with some amount of indices?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Say I have a (1,1) tensor $T^{\mu}_{\;\nu}$, I can represent it in some basis as follows (using Sean Carrol's notation):
$T= T^{\mu}_{\;\nu} \; \hat{e}_{(\mu)} \otimes \hat{\theta}^{(\nu)}$

If I let it act on some (1,0) tensor  $V=V^{\mu '} \hat{e}_{(\mu ')}$ I get (with $\times$ the usual product):

\begin{align} T(V)&=T^{\mu}_{\;\nu} \; \hat{e}_{(\mu)} \otimes \hat{\theta}^{(\nu)}(V^{\mu '} \hat{e}_{(\mu ')}) \\
&=T^{\mu}_{\;\nu} V^{\mu '} \hat{e}_{(\mu)} \times \hat{\theta}^{(\nu)}( \hat{e}_{(\mu ')}) \\
&=T^{\mu}_{\;\nu} V^{\mu '} \hat{e}_{(\mu)} \delta ^{\nu} _{\mu'}\\
&=T^{\mu}_{\nu}V^{\nu}\hat{e}_{(\mu)}
\end{align}

Would it be correct to say that the left hand side is not a tensor at all, but rather a geometric object that is coordinate/basis independent? The right hand side seems to imply that, because it has no "net" amount of indices.

And yet the left hand side also seems to say that it just lets a tensor act on a vector, so the output should be a vector, which it sort of is but not if you view it purely from an "index" perspective.

Is it because you can refer to a vector as "an independent geometric entity" and at the same time you often refer to the components of a vector as "a vector"? Is it the same thing with tensors? This might be vague, but in short: **is a tensor always identifiable as some symbol with some amount of indices?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tensor *is* coordinate independent; it is the components of a tensor that change under a coordinate transformation.

The result of acting on a vector with a $(1,1)$ tensor is a vector and your right hand side most definitely is, in the same way that something like $X^\mu \hat{e}_\mu$ is a vector (that has no net indices either) - yours just has more complicated components (i.e. $X^\mu=T^\mu_\nu V^\mu$). Vectors, being a special case of tensors, are also co-ordinate independent.

Physicists often refer to tensors by their components, which *do* change under a coordinate transformation, but *the tensors themselves do not*.

Comment: So what should I make of "a tensor is an object that transforms in a certain way"? Is this actually inaccurate, i.e. it should be "a tensor is an object whose components will transform in a specific way".

Comment: Yes, precisely!